# ViewPager отключить реакцию на прикосновение

Tags: android, java

Суть проблемы в том что нужно отключить реакцию на прикосновение с сохранением скроллинга ( есть n фрагментов которые переключаются табами ). 
Учитывая что есть настройки ( включить свайп, отключить свайп ) скроллинг нужен.

Буду рад любым мыслям, идеям, вариантам.

Comment: нечего непонятно, но можно попробовать чтото переопределить

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что верно интерпретировал ваш вопрос, но попробую.

Самый простой способ - переопределить *onInterceptTouchEvent* у *ViewPager*, возвращая *false* в случае, если свайп отключён, иначе, соответственно, *true*.

Если требуется более хитрая логика (включение/отключение свайпа в зависимости от каких-то условий, скорости жеста, *View*, на который приходится начало жеста и т.д.), то у *ViewPager* имеется метод *canScroll*.